# How to map and bind data in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two lists, one is the city list and another country list. suppose if I click Delhi (in city list). india will be auto-selected. country list is coming from the backend. here is an uncompleted demo. [demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pfcqiv)  give me some advice on what should be the approached or how can be it achieved. [image: screenshot]

Comment: This serious, people voting down a question without explanation. This should not be allowed. It seems a valid question, if you think not, explain why. I think, this bad behavior could be the end of Stackoverflow. Moderators, please guard carefully

Comment: yeah, I was thinking the same, why people are voting down. if anything is wrong in question I will edit the question, but voting down without explanation is not good

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question actually doesn't show much research effort, and we don't even know how the cities and the countries are related (I suppose this is a one-to-many relation in a relational database?)

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following. Instead of creating list city1 and city2 containing only the names of the cities, I would create a interface **to store the names of the city and the countries**, so you can use the country later to select the other list.

```
export interface City {
cityName: string;
country: string;
}
```

Then I would create two lists like this (before the constructor):

```js
  cityList1: City[] = [{cityName: 'delhi',country:'India'},
    {cityName: 'rudrapur',country:'India'},
    {cityName: 'kanpur',country:'India'}];
  selectedCity1: City = this.cityList1[0];
  countrySelectedInList1: string;

  cityList2: City[] = [{cityName: 'washington DC',country:'USA'},
    {cityName: 'New york',country:'USA'}];
  countrySelectedInList2: string;
```

Now you have also the country. Then In your **app.component.html** I would change you options to:

```html
<div class="container row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <p align="left" style="margin-left: -25px;" class="col-sm-3" >City1:</p>
                  <select class="col-sm-3" (ngModelChange)="changeCity1($event)" 
                  [style]="{'width':'140px'}" [ngModel]="selectedCity1">
                    <option  *ngFor="let city of cityList1" [ngValue]="city">{{city.cityName}}</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="container row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <p align="left" style="margin-left: -25px;" class="col-sm-3" >City2:</p>
                    <select class="col-sm-3" (ngModelChange)="changeCity2($event)" 
                  [style]="{'width':'140px'}" [ngModel]="selectedCity2">
                    <option  *ngFor="let city of cityList2" [ngValue]="city">{{city.cityName}}</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
```

And finally also in **app.component.ts** you will need the following functions to be executed when the options list is clicked and changed:

```
changeCity1(value:City){
    this.countrySelectedInList1 = value.country;
  }
  changeCity2(value:City){
    this.countrySelectedInList2 = value.country;
  }
```

So Now you have the countries stored in the variables **this.countrySelectedInList1** and **this.countrySelectedInList2**. So you will only need to change the selected country using that variables. You could do that using your variable named *selectedWindingProtection* inside the functions that I write you above and the variables countrySelectedInList1 and countrySelectedInList2 (I am not being very specific here because the code you posted in StackBlitz is not complete at this point).

Comment: @Prince Pandey , if you found the answer helpful, could you mark it as accepted answer ? I would appreciate it very much ;) .